# Vlookup formula isn't subtracting for certain cells and not others

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, vlookup

My Vlookup formula isn't subtracting the info it pulls from my pivot table and I can't figure out why.

I've run tests in other sheets and get the same results (works with some data but not others). I've also tested using other operators (`+`, `*`, `/`) and it brings back the correct info.

I've also tested just pulling the value from the pivot table over to a random cell to ensure that there were no errors with spaces, etc.

My formula looks like this:

```
=C2-VLOOKUP(E2,Benchmarks!A:E,3,FALSE)
```

This is in a cell where the value returned is correct and I've tried using it in others but get a `$0` returned for some reason.

This formula only works on *some* cells and not others even when I confirm that rows/columns are noted correctly in the formula.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you please share us with a sample?

Comment: [SOLVED]: Thanks all - but was able to figure it out. I was using the same data on both sheets which is why I was getting "0" for some return values. Thank you!